# ng build - Mangle private property names

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-click, uglifyjs

Why bundles generated with `ng build --prod` doesn't mangle / obfuscate / minimize class private properties? It would be a easy way to reduce the already fat enough Angular bundles.

Same thing would be useful with class properties used only in templates. From my point of view, they should be considered private, as they are part of the component internal behaviour, but AOT requires them to be public, breaking OOP encapsulation and difficulting minification.

Comment: Property names are private in TypeScript, but not in JavaScript. They become regular class properties at the point where minification happens.

Comment: Is there any way to improve this behaviour? I would like to use Closure Compiler Advanced, but it looks like it will break a lot of things

Comment: You'll need annotations in the code to use Closure. check out tsickle to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use typescript's "private fields" to mangle private property names

```
class MyClass {
   #privateProp: number;
}
```

This ensures that these properties are effectively hidden from outside access, and attempting to access them directly from other parts of the code will result in errors.